# AFNetworking POST Writes to Server and Returns Failure Error (Cocoa Error 3840)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I've been working on getting some jpg images uploaded to a server with AFNetworking 2.0 and some code I came across on stackoverflow, but I've been getting a Cocoa error 3840. I looked this up and found that some information regarding txt files, but I am not uploading txt files, so this has me confused. When I execute this code it starts writing to the server for a while until it crashes with the following statement:

> Failure Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)
>   UserInfo=0x155b1360 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with
>   array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

I am still new to AFNetworking so can someone please explain what is causing this error?

Also one other problem I'm having while writing this code is that I'm trying to save `NSData` by using the `dataWithContentsOfFile` method, but it keeps returning `nil` after using that method. I've tried multiple ways of doing it, which are coded out below. When I use the `pathForResource` (`_filename` contains the extension) for `fileRoot` it returns `nil`, but the other method `stringByAppendingPathComponent` works as expected, but then even after having the correct path as the parameter for `dataWithContentsOfFile` it still returns `nil` for `imageToUpload`. For now I just settled using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to get it working.

Can someone also please explain what might be causing that?

Sorry if I am not supposed to post 2 separate questions in one post. My first question is the most pressing. Thank you.

```
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                _username, @"username",
                                _filename, @"filename",
                                _metadata, @"metadata",
                                nil];

    // 1. Create `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` which will create your request.
    AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

    //NSString* fileRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:_filename ofType:nil];
    //NSString *fileRoot=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:_filename];
    //NSData *imageToUpload = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileRoot];
    NSData *imageToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_savedFiles[_selectedRowNumber], 1.0);

    // 2. Create an `NSMutableURLRequest`.
    NSMutableURLRequest *request =
    [serializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://69.91.198.44:8080/GeodatabaseServer/FileUpload"
                                    parameters:parameters
                     constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                         [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageToUpload
                                                     name:_filenameNoExt
                                                 fileName:_filename
                                                 mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                     }error:nil];

    // 3. Create and use `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` to create an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` from the `NSMutableURLRequest` that we just created.
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation =
    [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                         NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
                                     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                         NSLog(@"Failure %@", error.description);
                                     }];

    // 4. Set the progress block of the operation.
    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger __unused bytesWritten,
                                        long long totalBytesWritten,
                                        long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"Wrote %lld/%lld", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
    }];

    // 5. Begin!
    [operation start];
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the failure to upload by setting the following property:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
```

I was also able to fix my second issue by not using the bundle method and instead grabbing from my documents directory as follows:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:_filename];
```